# Code Synthesis - C++/Tree sub node serialization

Tags: c++, tree, mapping, codesynthesis

I'm using this great tool (http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/c++/tree/) to convert xsd into c++ code.

I'm trying to obtain the xml string from a sub node, but the only thing that i can get is the all xml, like this:

the all xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<people ....>

  <person id="1">
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <address>
      ....
    </address>
  </person>
...
```

I can get the all xml doing something like this:

```
people_t& p = ...
xml_schema::namespace_infomap map;
map[""].schema = "people.xsd";

// Serialize to a string.
//
std::ostringstream oss;
people (oss, p, map);
std::string xml (oss.str ());
```

But what i want is to get only the < address > xml sub node for example. This is possible to do? how can be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: guess that is not possible...

Comment: I wouldn't jump to a conclusion.  Not many people have looked at your question, and it is hard to believe somebody would go an build a tool for working with XML with making the elements of the XML tree somehow accessible.    So, there may still be answer you just haven't heard.  BTW, if this is a commercial product, doesn't it have a reference manual, and what does that manual say?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you want to use the no_xml_declaration flag.

```
people (oss, p, map, "UTF-8",
        xml_schema::flags::no_xml_declaration);
```

This suppresses the XML declaration, though for some versions of Xerces-C it results in a spurious newline at the beginning which you'll need to remove.
http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/xsd-users/2009-December/002625.html

For anyone else referencing this question later, you also need to invoke xsdcxx with --generate-serialization. By default only parse methods are emitted.

```
xsdcxx cxx-tree --generate-serialization {source XSD files}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you want to be able to serialize only the address element, you need to pass the `--root-element` option to the CodeSynthesis XSD command. In Ubuntu you would write

```
xsdcxx cxx-tree --root-element address --generate-serialization people.xsd
```

If you on the other hand just need to the value of the address, you could skip serialization altogether and just use the generated get function `address()`